# How to Filter the Linq Query?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Code below selects records from the database table "Sector" randomly.

```
return Model.GeneralDataAccessor.SelectListbyAsc<Model.Sector, GenelListObject, object>(
                p => true,
                p => new GenelListObject()
                {
                    Id1 = p.SectorId,
                    Note1= p.Note
                }, p => Guid.NewGuid(), 0, take);
```

I have been trying to modify the code to select certain records. Changed the final line to

```
p=>p.SectorId==19,0,take);
```

to get the record with the Id of 19.
But didn't work. What's the way to filter them by SectorId

Comment: What is [`SelectListbyAsc`](https://www.google.com/search?q=SelectListbyAsc)?

Comment: That's a custom method and not a LINQ method, looking at the code I guess that you should substitute `p => true` with your constraint.

Comment: @Kobi SelectListByAsc upthere

Comment: @Zache That returned all records

Comment: I meant that you should replace `p => true` with `p => p.SectorID == 19`, it's the first parameter that is used to filter the query according to the method you provided.

Also, this is a question for your co-workers/teammembers. You are asking about using a method that is specific to whateve project you are working on. Or part of a framework that isn't any of those tagged as far as I know

Comment: @Zack Worked like charm! Sorry I got it wrong in the first place

Comment: I advice you to use SqlFunctions.Rand() instead of Guid.NewGuid(), it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

i think put below condition block.

```
.where(p=>p.SectorId == 19)
```